# how to make a sign in button which displays users name and balance ONLY if correct pin is entered?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a app something like a banking app however I want the user to enter their pin e.g. 1111 and hit enter, then if the pin is correct users name and balance will be displayed if the pin is wrong "wrong pin!" message will be displayed.

I'm struggling to make the correct pin work, every number I enter prints out the "wrong pin" message rather than the name and balance.

code I used for enter button:

```
int moInt = 1111;

String moString = "1111";

String intAsString = Integer.toString(moInt);

double balance = 10000.00;

if (moString.equals(moInt)) {

    System.out.println("Hi Mohamed" +  "\nYour balance is" + " £" + balance);
    ATM a = new ATM();
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setResizable(false);


} else{

    System.out.println("Wrong Pin!");
}

I tried this 

if (moString.equals(moString)) {

    System.out.println("Hi Mohamed" +  "\nYour balance is" + " £" + balance);
    ATM a = new ATM();
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setResizable(false);
```

this prints out the name and balance however it does that with any number.

the specific pin or number am trying to use is 1111.

HELP PLEASE been stuck on this for AGES!!! :'(

Comment: Look at `moString.equals(moInt)`, this equates to `String.equals(int)`, which will never be `true`...

Comment: You probably want `moString.equals(intAsString)` instead of `moString.equals(moInt)`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `moString.equals(moInt)`, this equates to `String.equals(int)`, which will never be `true`...

You probably meant to use `moString.equals(intAsString )`

FYI- From a security point of view, `String` is not a good choice for storing sensitive data, either maintain it in a `char` array or as it's a number, as an `int` value

Comment: Ah thanks for helping me out and also thanks for letting me know from a security point of view, i  never knew

Answer (score 0):

In Java, integers and strings are as separate as can be. No integer can be equal to a string.

What you have to do is convert the string to an integer, then compare it to the other integer. Change the `if` to this:

```
if (moInt == Integer.parseInt(moString))
```